# Migrating JIRA issues to GitLab? In 2020

Tags: gitlab, jira, migrate

Is there a way to migrate JIRA issues to GitLab?

I use Gitlab Version 12.6.4.

However, I only find ways to import my Jira tasks via the API v3. But it was removed in Gitlab 11.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is some effort made here, but i guess you found that one already:

https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/08/21/migrating-your-jira-issues-into-gitlab/

I guess if you have lots of plugins like timesheet the approache is not that easy.
If you have experience to share I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "bulk-import" for the work items to import into gitlab.
[GitLab Docu, CSV import](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/csv_import.html)

Jira can export the issus as
[Atlasian Jira Export](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/export-issues/)